# Video and music not appearing in WPF when used as an asset

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.7.2

I'm now entering WPF and I had a question, although it seems simple, I'm still learning

I am creating an application that shows a video and a song when it opens.

If I define the full path like:

```
C:\myapp\media.mp4
```

Using this path in Source works normally

the problem starts when I add the video and music as a resource, it stops working

[image]

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
<Grid>
<StackPanel Height="768" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="1024" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <MediaElement x:Name="Mymedia" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1024" Height="768">
        <MediaElement.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <MediaTimeline Source="Assets/media.mp4" Storyboard.TargetName="Mymedia"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </MediaElement.Triggers>
         <MediaElement.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <MediaTimeline Source="Assets/isurge.mp3" Storyboard.TargetName="Mymedia"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </MediaElement.Triggers>
    </MediaElement>
</StackPanel>
```

using resource the video does not run can someone tell me why?

Comment: Set Copy to Output Directory to `Copy if newer` and see what happens.

Comment: @RaoHammas 
still does not display

Comment: @RaoHammas That would copy the video file alongside the compiled binaries. I think OP wants to bundle the video within the final exe and not rely on an external file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem to play a "resource" audio/video file using `MediaElement`. It's seems the media element does not support packed URI like `Source="pack://application:,,,/Assets/media.mp4"`.

Similar issue is described on the Microsoft forum:

[Using Relative File Path in MediaTimeline](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/83246978-a5b5-45c8-a9ba-0856ffda83b6/using-relative-file-path-in-mediatimeline?forum=wpf)

[How to play a "resource" audio file using MediaElement?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f4594675-9ddd-4db0-b758-86e112edc74a/how-to-play-a-quotresourcequot-audio-file-using-mediaelement?forum=wpf)

But it is possible to obtain audio/video from the resources and set the `MediaTimeline` source programmatically.
The idea is extract audio/media content from a resources and write it to the temporary file. Then set URI for the `MediaTimeline` source to make reference to the temporary file.

### Example:

> Set a file *Build Action* to `Embedded Resource`.

> In the code:

```
  var resourceName = "YourAssemblyName.Assets.isurge.mp3";
  using (var fstream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
  {
      var ext = resourceName.Substring(resourceName.LastIndexOf("."));
      var pathfile = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext;
      using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(pathfile, FileMode.Create))
      {
          fstream.CopyTo(outputFileStream);
      }
      mt.Source = new Uri(pathfile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
  }
```

> Set the `MediaTimeline` name:

```
 <MediaTimeline x:Name="mt" Storyboard.TargetName="audio" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
```

*NOTE: Temporary created file should be deleted when it no longer needed.*

Comment: This would still rely on the video file being present in the exe folder, completely ignoring the resources. Probably the OP wants to bundle the file within the final compiled exe without any external file.

Comment: I'm really going to have to leave the content exposed, is there a way to pack the video and audio in a file, encrypted like a file.client

Comment: @carl - If it is necessary to encrypt the video content the easiest way is to encrypt a video file before adding it to an application resources (for example, by using asymmetric encryption) and decrypt it at runtime.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution, saved so much of my time.!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you may just not have the correct path. Try using something like the following:

```
<MediaTimeline Source="pack://application:,,,/Assets/media.mp4" Storyboard.TargetName="Mymedia"/>
```

This works for me when building .NET Core WPF apps, other versions of .NET may vary.

Comment: I am using the net framework 4.7.2 I even tried to use it that way without success